# How do I Publish pcd files in my folder on a topic?

Tags: ros, pcl, sensor-msgs, pointcloud, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have 100 pcd files.
they look like this

VERSION .7
FIELDS x y z rgb
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F U
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 38092
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 38092
DATA ascii
224 0 681 2172952
229 0 662 2107159
....

Now I want to publish these files one by one on a topic . How do I do that?
I have gone through the pcl ros tutorials.They subscribe to a topic, do some processing inside the call back function and then they publish it on a topic.

What I want to do is just publish these pcd files on a topic

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62123/how-do-i-publish-pcd-files-in-my-folder-on-a-topic?/) by [Rohitdewani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4133/rohitdewani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the wiki page for [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros).  In particular, it depends on what ROS message type you'd like to publish.  If your PCD contains generic pointCloud data, then it looks like you could probably use `pcd_to_pointcloud`, which publises ROS [PointCloud2](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) messages:

```
 $ rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud <file.pcd> [ <interval> ]
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-04-30**:
How to add this in launch file or python script?